# Object alterable value not initiating initialValues={values} form.item antd form in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, ng-zorro-antd

I've included a sample of code showing how I initiate the value in the form; were you able to spot any errors? I'm not sure why it's not initiating the value.

```
formValues = {
      dummy:{
         key:value,
         key1:value,
         key2:value
      },
      dummykey:{
          name: value,
          fullname: value,
      },
}

<Form name='myform' form={form} initialValues={formValues} onFinish={onFinished}>
  <>
    {Object.Keys(formValues.dummy).map((objKey) =>{
          return (
            <Row>
              <Col span={6}> {objKey}  </Col> 
              <Col span={6}> <Form.Item name={objKey} key={objKey} </Col> 
            </Row>
        )}
    )}

    {Object.Keys(formValues.dummykey).map((objKey) =>{
      return (
        <Row>
          <Col span={6}> {objKey}  </Col> 
          <Col span={6}> <Form.Item name={objKey} key={objKey} </Col> 
        </Row>
      )}
    )}
  </>
</Form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you missed closing the `<Form.Item>` component in your code. You need to add the closing tag `</Form.Item>` for each of the `Form.Item` components.

```
<Form name='myform' form={form} initialValues={formValues} onFinish={onFinished}>
  {Object.keys(formValues.dummy).map((objKey) => {
    return (
      <Row>
        <Col span={6}> {objKey} </Col>
        <Col span={6}>
          <Form.Item name={['dummy', objKey]} key={objKey}>
            {/* Add your input component here */}
          </Form.Item>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    )
  })}

  {Object.keys(formValues.dummykey).map((objKey) => {
    return (
      <Row>
        <Col span={6}> {objKey} </Col>
        <Col span={6}>
          <Form.Item name={['dummykey', objKey]} key={objKey}>
            {/* Add your input component here */}
          </Form.Item>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    )
  })}
</Form>
```